# Finding the “modal curve” from multiple time series

Tags: python, curve-fitting

Suppose I have multiple time series, which are different lengths. Is there a way to get the most common shape from these multiple time series? Something like curve fitting to multiple curves?

I’ve tried clustering the curves with dynamic time warping, but I want one curve which best captures the different curves

Comment: Can you show an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the most common subshape in all the time series, that is called the consensus motif, and there is an algorithm for that https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/consensus_Motif_ICDM_Long_version.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for this - I’m not looking to  find a pattern of a certain length, I want to curve fit to multiple time series of different lengths